# Hover effects on list item 3

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get li hover effect like the one on the right side bar of this page http://smokefree.gov/health-effects

as you see when you hover the background color and text color change

this is the code :

```css
#ASIDE_1 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    float: left;
    height: 528.171875px;
    min-height: 30px;
    width: 298.859375px;
    perspective-origin: 149.421875px 264.078125px;
    transform-origin: 149.421875px 264.078125px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/26.0399990081787px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 13.4399995803833px 12.015625px 0px 8.3125px;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#ASIDE_1*/

#DIV_2 {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    height: 232px;
    width: 298.859375px;
    perspective-origin: 149.421875px 116px;
    transform-origin: 149.421875px 116px;
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/26.0399990081787px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_2*/

#DIV_3 {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    height: 232px;
    width: 298.859375px;
    perspective-origin: 149.421875px 116px;
    transform-origin: 149.421875px 116px;
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/26.0399990081787px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}/*#DIV_3*/

#IMG_4 {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    display: block;
    height: 232px;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 298.859375px;
    perspective-origin: 149.421875px 116px;
    transform-origin: 149.421875px 116px;
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/26.0399990081787px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#IMG_4*/

#DIV_5 {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    height: 283.171875px;
    width: 298.859375px;
    perspective-origin: 149.421875px 148.078125px;
    transform-origin: 149.421875px 148.078125px;
    border-top: 13px solid rgb(240, 240, 240);
    border-right: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-bottom: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-left: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/26.0399990081787px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_5*/

#UL_6 {
    color: rgb(84, 84, 84);
    height: 283.171875px;
    width: 298.859375px;
    perspective-origin: 149.421875px 141.578125px;
    transform-origin: 149.421875px 141.578125px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(84, 84, 84);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/26.0399990081787px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: rgb(84, 84, 84) none 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}/*#UL_6*/

#LI_7 {
    color: rgb(181, 96, 0);
    height: 92.390625px;
    min-height: 92.3999938964844px;
    width: 283.921875px;
    perspective-origin: 149.421875px 47.1875px;
    transform-origin: 149.421875px 47.1875px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border-top: 0px none rgb(181, 96, 0);
    border-right: 0px none rgb(181, 96, 0);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(240, 240, 240);
    border-left: 0px none rgb(181, 96, 0);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/20px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    outline: rgb(181, 96, 0) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 14.9375px;
}/*#LI_7*/

#A_8, #A_15, #A_22 {
    color: rgb(0, 136, 204);
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0px none rgb(0, 136, 204);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/20px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    outline: rgb(0, 136, 204) none 0px;
}/*#A_8, #A_15, #A_22*/

#DIV_9, #DIV_16, #DIV_23 {
    color: rgb(0, 136, 204);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 73.390625px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 232.8125px;
    perspective-origin: 116.40625px 36.6875px;
    transform-origin: 116.40625px 36.6875px;
    border: 0px none rgb(0, 136, 204);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/20px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    outline: rgb(0, 136, 204) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_9, #DIV_16, #DIV_23*/

#H2_10 {
    color: rgb(181, 96, 0);
    height: 39px;
    text-align: left;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
    width: 220.21875px;
    perspective-origin: 110.109375px 19.5px;
    transform-origin: 110.109375px 19.5px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(181, 96, 0);
    font: normal normal bold normal 25px/39.0599975585938px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px 12.5999994277954px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(181, 96, 0) none 0px;
}/*#H2_10*/

#P_11, #P_18, #P_25 {
    color: rgb(84, 84, 84);
    height: 26px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 232.8125px;
    perspective-origin: 116.40625px 13px;
    transform-origin: 116.40625px 13px;
    border: 0px none rgb(84, 84, 84);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/26.0399990081787px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px 0px 8.39999961853027px;
    outline: rgb(84, 84, 84) none 0px;
}/*#P_11, #P_18, #P_25*/

#DIV_12 {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    color: rgb(0, 136, 204);
    float: right;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 28.390625px;
    perspective-origin: 14.1875px 17.5px;
    transform-origin: 14.1875px 17.5px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(http://smokefree.gov/sites/all/themes/sfg/images/content/smokefree-content-page-related-link-ong-mobile-43x43.png) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px / 90% padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(0, 136, 204);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/20px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 25px 8.39999961853027px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(0, 136, 204) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_12*/

#IMG_13, #IMG_20, #IMG_27 {
    color: rgb(0, 136, 204);
    height: 1px;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 1px;
    perspective-origin: 0.5px 0.5px;
    transform-origin: 0.5px 0.5px;
    border: 0px none rgb(0, 136, 204);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/20px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    outline: rgb(0, 136, 204) none 0px;
}/*#IMG_13, #IMG_20, #IMG_27*/

#LI_14 {
    color: rgb(0, 128, 171);
    height: 92.390625px;
    min-height: 92.3999938964844px;
    width: 283.921875px;
    perspective-origin: 149.421875px 47.1875px;
    transform-origin: 149.421875px 47.1875px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border-top: 0px none rgb(0, 128, 171);
    border-right: 0px none rgb(0, 128, 171);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(240, 240, 240);
    border-left: 0px none rgb(0, 128, 171);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/20px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    outline: rgb(0, 128, 171) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 14.9375px;
}/*#LI_14*/

#H2_17 {
    color: rgb(0, 128, 171);
    height: 39px;
    text-align: left;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
    width: 220.21875px;
    perspective-origin: 110.109375px 19.5px;
    transform-origin: 110.109375px 19.5px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(0, 128, 171);
    font: normal normal bold normal 25px/39.0599975585938px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px 12.5999994277954px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(0, 128, 171) none 0px;
}/*#H2_17*/

#DIV_19 {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    color: rgb(0, 136, 204);
    float: right;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 28.390625px;
    perspective-origin: 14.1875px 17.5px;
    transform-origin: 14.1875px 17.5px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(http://smokefree.gov/sites/all/themes/sfg/images/content/smokefree-content-page-related-link-blu-mobile-43x43.png) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px / 90% padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(0, 136, 204);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/20px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 25px 8.39999961853027px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(0, 136, 204) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_19*/

#LI_21 {
    color: rgb(96, 128, 24);
    height: 92.390625px;
    min-height: 92.3999938964844px;
    width: 283.921875px;
    perspective-origin: 149.421875px 47.1875px;
    transform-origin: 149.421875px 47.1875px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border-top: 0px none rgb(96, 128, 24);
    border-right: 0px none rgb(96, 128, 24);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(240, 240, 240);
    border-left: 0px none rgb(96, 128, 24);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/20px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    outline: rgb(96, 128, 24) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 14.9375px;
}/*#LI_21*/

#H2_24 {
    color: rgb(96, 128, 24);
    height: 39px;
    text-align: left;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
    width: 220.21875px;
    perspective-origin: 110.109375px 19.5px;
    transform-origin: 110.109375px 19.5px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(96, 128, 24);
    font: normal normal bold normal 25px/39.0599975585938px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px 12.5999994277954px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(96, 128, 24) none 0px;
}/*#H2_24*/

#DIV_26 {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    color: rgb(0, 136, 204);
    float: right;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 28.390625px;
    perspective-origin: 14.1875px 17.5px;
    transform-origin: 14.1875px 17.5px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(http://smokefree.gov/sites/all/themes/sfg/images/content/smokefree-content-page-related-link-grn-mobile-43x43.png) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px / 90% padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(0, 136, 204);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/20px cabinregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 25px 8.39999961853027px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(0, 136, 204) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_26*/
```

```html
<aside id="ASIDE_1">
 <div id="DIV_2">
  <div id="DIV_3">
   <img alt="Male Teen" src="http://www.battalha.com/up/pic/2.1%20smoke%20effect.jpg" id="IMG_4" />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="DIV_5">
  <ul id="UL_6">
   <li id="LI_7">
    <a href="http://smokefree.gov/rewards-of-quitting" title="Live a smokefree life" id="A_8"></a>
    <div id="DIV_9">
     <h2 id="H2_10">
      Live a smokefree life
     </h2>
     <p id="P_11">
      Discover the rewards of quitting
     </p>
    </div>
    <div id="DIV_12">
     <img alt="" src="/sites/all/themes/sfg/images/content/spacer.png" id="IMG_13" />
    </div>
   </li>
   <li id="LI_14">
    <a href="http://smokefree.gov/cravings" title="Craving cigarettes?" id="A_15"></a>
    <div id="DIV_16">
     <h2 id="H2_17">
      Craving cigarettes?
     </h2>
     <p id="P_18">
      Get tips for when the urge hits
     </p>
    </div>
    <div id="DIV_19">
     <img alt="" src="/sites/all/themes/sfg/images/content/spacer.png" id="IMG_20" />
    </div>
   </li>
   <li id="LI_21">
    <a href="http://smokefree.gov/steps-on-quit-day" title="Quitting today?" id="A_22"></a>
    <div id="DIV_23">
     <h2 id="H2_24">
      Quitting today?
     </h2>
     <p id="P_25">
      Review steps for your quit day
     </p>
    </div>
    <div id="DIV_26">
     <img alt="" src="/sites/all/themes/sfg/images/content/spacer.png" id="IMG_27" />
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Don't look like no Java to me.  I've retagged accordingly.

Comment: Add this to your CSS: `#UL_6 li:hover { background-color: #00F; }`. Also read about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @dave: so close to what i want .. but how to change specific li .. not all the li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the source of the page you linked to, the CSS rules that are being applied that change the background color and text color are as follows:

```
.li-first:hover,
.li-first:hover H2,
.li-first:hover A,
.li-first:hover A:visited H2 {
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #b56000;
    color:#ffffff;
}

...

.li-second:hover,
.li-second:hover H2,
.li-second:hover A,
.li-second:hover A:visited H2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0080ab;
    color: #ffffff;
}

...

.li-third:hover,
.li-third:hover H2,
.li-third:hover A,
.li-third:hover A:visited H2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #608018;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

So what's actually happening is the `li` element itself is having its background color changed (to a different color for each of the three `li` elements), and the descendent elements that have text content are having both their background color and text color changed as well (text to white).

You can apply the same design to your code, taking into account the differences between your code and the site code:

```
#LI_7:hover, #LI_7:hover h2, #LI_7:hover p { background-color:#b56000; color:#ffffff; }
#LI_14:hover, #LI_14:hover h2, #LI_14:hover p { background-color:#0080ab; color:#ffffff; }
#LI_21:hover, #LI_21:hover h2, #LI_21:hover p { background-color:#608018; color:#ffffff; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9juf1nLf/

**Edit:** Sorry, I didn't notice that the image had changed! After some investigation, this is the CSS rule that's changing the image:

```
.li-first:hover .image-note,
.li-second:hover .image-note,
.li-third:hover .image-note {
    background: url("../images/content/smokefree-content-page-related-link-ro-mobile-43x43.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / 90% auto transparent;
}
```

So what's happening is that they're replacing the entire image with an alternative one when you hover over the `li`. It's also a bit strange, as the `.image-note` class is actually being applied to a `div` that contains an `img` element. The `img` element is just applying a blank spacer, while the `div` is actually showing the visible image as its background image.

Also interesting is that they're using the exact same hover image for all three `li`s. This works because although the image needs to be colored differently when you're *not* hovering over it, when you *are* hovering over it, it's just the same plain white image for all three `li`s.

For comparison, here's the first colored image compared to the common white image:

http://smokefree.gov/sites/all/themes/sfg/images/content/smokefree-content-page-related-link-ong-mobile-43x43.png

http://smokefree.gov/sites/all/themes/sfg/images/content/smokefree-content-page-related-link-ro-mobile-43x43.png

Anyway, you can apply this to your code as well with the following:

```
#LI_7:hover #DIV_12, #LI_14:hover #DIV_19, #LI_21:hover #DIV_26 { background-image:url('http://smokefree.gov/sites/all/themes/sfg/images/content/smokefree-content-page-related-link-ro-mobile-43x43.png'); }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9juf1nLf/2/

Comment: thanks so much that really explained everything, but what about the side image next to the li .. how does it invert

Answer (score 0):

From Chrome's 'inspect element' it would appear that the list is using CSS :hover selector.

```
.li_foo:hover { 
 background: #B56000;color: #FFFFFF;}
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp